# Why can I sometimes concatenate audio data using NodeJS Buffers, and sometimes I cannot?

Tags: node.js, audio, concatenation, buffer, mp3

As part of a project I am working on, there is a requirement to concatenate multiple pieces of audio data into one large audio file. The audio files are generated from four sources, and the individual files are stored in a Google Cloud storage bucket. Each file is an mp3 file, and it is easy to verify that each individual file is generating correctly (individually, I can play them, edit them in my favourite software, etc.).

To merge the audio files together, a nodejs server loads the files from the Google Cloud storage as an array buffer using an axios POST request. From there, it puts each array buffer into a node Buffer using `Buffer.from()`, so now we have an array of Buffer objects. Then it uses `Buffer.concat()` to concatenate the Buffer objects into one big Buffer, which we then convert to Base64 data and send to the client server.

This is cool, but the issue arises when concatenating audio generated from different sources. The 4 sources I mentioned above are Text to Speech software platforms, such as Google Cloud Voice and Amazon Polly. Specifically, we have files from Google Cloud Voice, Amazon Polly, IBM Watson, and Microsoft Azure Text to Speech. Essentially just five text to speech solutions. Again, all individual files work, but when concatenating them together via this method there are some interesting effects.

When the sound files are concatenated, seemingly depending on which platform they originate from, the sound data either will or will not be included in the final sound file. Below is a 'compatibility' table based on my testing:

```
|------------|--------|--------|-----------|-----|
| Platform / | Google | Amazon | Microsoft | IBM |
|------------|--------|--------|-----------|-----|
| Google     | Yes    | No     | No        | No  |
|------------|--------|--------|-----------|-----|
| Amazon     |        | No     | No        | Yes |
|------------|--------|--------|-----------|-----|
| Microsoft  |        |        | Yes       | No  |
|------------|--------|--------|-----------|-----|
| IBM        |        |        |           | Yes |
|------------|--------|--------|-----------|-----|
```

The effect is as follows: When I play the large output file, it will always start playing the first sound file included. From there, if the next sound file is compatible, it is heard, otherwise it is skipped entirely (no empty sound or anything). If it was skipped, the 'length' of that file (for example 10s long audio file) is included at the end of the generated output sound file. However, the moment that my audio player hits the point where the last 'compatible' audio has played, it immediately skips to the end.

As a scenario:

```
Input:
sound1.mp3 (3s) -> Google
sound2.mp3 (5s) -> Amazon
sound3.mp3 (7s)-> Google
sound4.mp3 (11s) -> IBM

Output:
output.mp3 (26s) -> first 10s is sound1 and sound3, last 16s is skipped.
```

In this case, the output sound file would be 26s seconds long. For the first 10 seconds, you would hear the `sound1.mp3` and `sound3.mp3` played back to back. Then at 10s (at least playing this mp3 file in firefox) the player immediately skips to the end at 26s.

My question is: Does anyone have any ideas why sometimes I can concatenate audio data in this way, and other times I cannot? And how come there is this 'missing' data included at the end of the output file? Shouldn't concatenating the binary data work in all cases if it works for some cases, as all the files have mp3 encoding? If I am wrong please let me know what I can do to successfully concatenate any mp3 files :)
I can provide my nodeJS backend code, but the process and methods used are described above.

Thanks for reading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Potential Sources of Problems

#### Sample Rate

44.1 kHz is often used for music, as it's what is used on CD audio.  48 kHz is usually used for video, as it's what was used on DVDs.  Both of those sample rates are much higher than is required for speech, so it's likely that your various text-to-speech providers are outputting something different.  22.05 kHz (half of 44.1 kHz) is common, and 11.025 kHz is out there too.

While each frame specifies its own sample rate, making it possible to generate a stream with varying sample rates, I've never seen a decoder attempt to switch sample rates mid-stream.  I suspect that the decoder is skipping these frames, or maybe even skipping over an arbitrary block until it gets consistent data again.

Use something like [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html) (or FFprobe) to figure out what the sample rates of your files are:

```
ffmpeg -i sound2.mp3
```

You'll get an output like this:

```
Duration: 00:13:50.22, start: 0.011995, bitrate: 192 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
```

In this example, 44.1 kHz is the sample rate.

#### Channel Count

I'd expect your voice MP3s to be in mono, but it wouldn't hurt to check to be sure.  As with above, check the output of FFmpeg.  In my example above, it says `stereo`.

As with sample rate, technically each frame could specify its own channel count but I don't know of any player that will pull off switching channel count mid-stream.  Therefore, if you're concatenating, you need to make sure all the channel counts are the same.

#### ID3 Tags

It's common for there to be [ID3 metadata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3) at the beginning (ID3v2) and/or end (ID3v1) of the file.  It's less expected to have this data mid-stream.  You would want to make sure this metadata is all stripped out before concatenating.

#### MP3 Bit Reservoir

MP3 frames don't necessarily stand alone.  If you have a constant bitrate stream, the encoder may still use less data to encode one frame, and more data to encode another.  When this happens, some frames contain data for other frames.  That way, frames that could benefit from the extra bandwidth can get it while still fitting the whole stream within a constant bitrate.  This is the "bit reservoir".

If you cut a stream and splice in another stream, you may split up a frame and its dependent frames.  This typically causes an audio glitch, but may also cause the decoder to skip ahead.  Some badly behaving decoders will just stop playing altogether.  In your example, you're not cutting anything so this probably isn't the source of your trouble... but I mention it here because it's definitely relevant to the way you're working these streams.

*See also:  http://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=Bit_reservoir*

### Solutions

#### Pick a "normal" format, resample and rencode non-conforming files

If most of your sources are all the exact same format and only one or two outstanding, you could convert the non-conforming file.  From there, strip ID3 tags from everything and concatenate away.

To do the conversion, I'd recommend kicking it over to FFmpeg as a [child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html).

```
child_process.spawn('ffmpeg' [
  // Input
  '-i', inputFile, // Use '-' to write to STDIN instead

  // Set sample rate
  '-ar', '44100',

  // Set audio channel count
  '-ac', '1',

  // Audio bitrate... try to match others, but not as critical
  '-b:a', '64k',

  // Ensure we output an MP3
  '-f', 'mp3',

  // Output
  outputFile // As with input, use '-' to write to STDOUT
]);
```

#### Best Solution: Let FFmpeg (or similar) do the work for you

The simplest, most robust solution to all of this is to let FFmpeg build a brand new stream for you.  This will cause your audio files to be decoded to PCM, and a new stream made.  You can add parameters to resample those inputs, and modify channel counts if needed.  Then output one stream.  Use the [concat filter](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#filter).

This way, you can accept audio files of any type, you don't have to write the code to hack those streams together, and once setup you won't have to worry about it.

The only downside is that it will require a re-encoding of everything, meaning another generation of quality lost.  This would be required for any non-conforming files anyway, and it's just speech, so I wouldn't give it a second thought.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Over the last few days I've been trying out your suggestions. First, I tried the solution of letting FFMpeg handle everything, but because in my case the input files are stored on Google Cloud Storage, we have the files in memory instead of on the server HD. Unfortunately, because ffmpeg only has stdin to support reading from memory (from what I could find), it supports one input stream instead of multiple. Because of that, I'm trying the first suggestion (convert each file then concat). I'll report results when I have them! Thanks again!

Comment: @Japser36 Cool, glad you got it working.  Note that FFmpeg can read HTTP(S) URLs as inputs, so you could always sign a URL from Cloud Storage direction and use as inputs if you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

@Brad's answer was the solution! The first solution he suggested worked. It took some messing around getting FFMpeg to work correctly, but in the end using the [fluent-ffmpeg](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg) library worked.

Each file in my case was stored on Google Cloud Storage, and not on the server's hard drive. This posed some problems for FFmpeg, as it requires file paths to have multiple files, or an input stream (but only one is supported, as there is only one STDIN).

One solution is to put the files on the hard drive temporarily, but this would not work for our use case as we may have a lot of use in this function and the hard drive adds latency.

So, instead we did as suggested and loaded each file into ffmpeg to convert it into a standardized format. This was a bit tricky, but in the end requesting each file as a stream, using that stream as an input for ffmpeg, then using fluent-ffmpeg's `pipe()` method (which returns a stream) as output worked.

We then bound an event listener to the 'data' event for this pipe, and pushed the data to an array (`bufs.push(data)`), and on stream 'end' we concatenated this array using `Buffer.concat(bufs)`, followed by a promise resolve. 
Then once all requests promises were resolved, we could be sure ffmpeg had processed each file, and then those buffers were concatenated in the required groups as before using `Buffer.concat()`, converted to base64 data, and sent to the client.

This works great, and now it seems to be able to handle every combination of files/sources I can throw at it!

**In conclusion:**

The answer to the question was that the mp3 data must have been encoded differently (different channels, sample rates, etc.), and loading it through ffmpeg and outputing it in a 'unified' way made the mp3 data compatible.

The solution was to process each file in ffmpeg separately, pipe the ffmpeg output into a buffer, then concatenate the buffers.

Thanks @Brad for your suggestions and detailed answer!

Comment: Why are you converting to base64 to send to the client?  You should be able to keep it binary.

Comment: This is how we had the system set up before. This 'get merged data' from the server is based on a copy of a 'get single data' for a single sound file. The developer who wrote that piece of code sent the data as base64, which is why this new function also sends the data as base64. No other particular reason than that. The client receives the data, creates a file out of it, and presents it to the user for download. Is there a clear benefit to sending the binary versus the base64 data,  other than time spend converting to/from base64?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.  Base64 encoding the data adds 33% overhead in size, in addition to CPU and memory requirements on each end.  And, of course there's a minor amount of added complexity.  There is no reason for this waste.

Comment: Thanks again for the info :) I started implementing send the binary data instead of base64 data, but I then discovered why we use the base64 data in the first place: our client server expects a JSON object with multiple other bits of metadata, and binary isnt supported in JSON hence the base64 encoding. I understand that we could send error status codes instead, but then there is still the issue of sending multiple files as binary data via one request, as sometimes the server combines (for example) files A and B, and separately C and D. It was easiest to leave it as two base64 strings.

Comment: For the request data, it's trivial to use multipart form data.  This is the usual way that it's done.  (Imagine a normal form element with multiple file inputs.)  You can have your data, even JSON if you wanted, as well as all the files.  This will save overhead on the clients as they can stream that HTTP request data, as well as saving bandwidth, and reducing overhead on the server.  Also, it doesn't sound necessary for your use case but there's always CBOR.  It's trivial to parse in JavaScript, supports streaming, binary types, dates, and more.

Comment: Hi @Brad, we tried implementing sending the binary directly to the client, but found that for our purposes of having to send multiple files and pieces of data to the client from the server through multipart/form-data did not work. The client would receive the data response from the server as the raw multipart formdata text instead of decoding it into separate pieces. From what I could find, there is no easy way to parse multipart/form-data in a client browser, as most solutions are server implementations requiring node, or you have to do it manually.